# How to insert an array concatenation in a csv file?

Tags: php, csv, fputcsv

I retrieve values from a csv file by reading it and I would like to write these values in a .txt file and have each line of the file be like this :
MMXC1_" | 48654641 | 1 | 2

But when I send it I get "Notice: Array to string conversion", what do I do?

```
$constante[] = "MMXC1_";

$temp = array_column($resultat, 'MAGCOD', 'MAGAS400');


if (($handle = fopen("$nomcsv", "r")) !== FALSE) { 

    $firstLine = true;

    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000000, ";")) !== FALSE) 
    {   
        if(!$firstLine) {

            $EAN[] = $temp[$data[3]];
            $min[] = $data[12];
            $max[] = $data[13];


        }
        $firstLine = false;
    }   
}


$data_final[] = $constante.'|'.$EAN.'|'.$min.'|'.$max; 


$cheminfile = "C:/wamp64/www/retail/csv/csv/csv_finaux/MMX".date('His').".txt";

$fp = fopen("$cheminfile", "w");

$delimiter = ';';

fputcsv($fp, $data_final, $delimiter);                              

fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Your values `$EAN` etc are built as arrays, you then try and build a string from them `$constante.'|'.$EAN.'|'.$min.'|'.$max`.  You may be better off writing each line out as you read it, save storing it.

Comment: Just a minor point - you correctly don't process the read of the file if you can't open it, but always write the data out (even if the file hasn't been read).

Comment: What do I have to change then?

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite your code as:

```
$constante = "MMXC1_";  // it is a STRING

$temp = array_column($resultat, 'MAGCOD', 'MAGAS400');

if (($handle = fopen("$nomcsv", "r")) !== FALSE) { 
    $firstLine = true;
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000000, ";")) !== FALSE) 
    {   
        if(!$firstLine) {
            // Create line here and immediately add it to `$data_final`
            $data_final[] = $constante.'|'.$temp[$data[3]].'|'.$data[12].'|'.$data[13]; 
         }
         $firstLine = false;
    }   
}

$cheminfile = "C:/wamp64/www/retail/csv/csv/csv_finaux/MMX".date('His').".txt";
$fp = fopen("$cheminfile", "w");

$delimiter = ';';

fputcsv($fp, $data_final, $delimiter);                              

fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanations, it works perfectly!

Comment: Wouldn't the this act as though each value in the output file is a value of `$data_final` and separate them with a `;`?

Comment: Each value is separated by a "|" and between each $data_final value we put a ";"